# bootstrap-datepicker sends wrong date format

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

The date tag in HTML5 (`<input type="date">`) always sends data in YYYY-MM-DD format, disregarding what format users might be using. That's great, but browser's default controls are usually ugly.

So, I'm trying to use [bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to help users choosing dates. I launch it like this, and it opens correctly:

```
$('#expirationDate').datepicker({
     format: "dd.mm.yyyy"
});
```

Unfortunately, `bootstrap-datepicker` seems to send to the server the chosen date in user's format (ie. DD/MM/YYYY). This is obviously a problem, since users might have different preferences.

**Is `bootstrap-datepicker` capable of sending data in "YYYY-MM-DD" format,  disregarding user's local format?** To me, that's "common-sense"  functionality, but I didn't find any documentation about it.

If the answer to above question is "no", can you please recommend another date picker that integrates well with Symfony 3 and Twig?

Comment: Check The My Ans ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible without javascript or php processing. That's pretty sad, as this is a really common situation.

My solution was to use `JQuery UI` instead of `bootstrap-datepicker`. I created two fields:

- a hidden field that stores the date in YYYY-MM-DD and whose value is processed in backend
- a visible field that is used by DatePicker but it is not processed by backend.

On the second field, I used [altField](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) and [altFormat](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat) to populate the first field:

```
$(function () {
    $("#theDateUI").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            altField: $("#theDate"),
            altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**In PHP**

mysql database needs date format in `Y-m-d` format so in case to insert this date format in the database you will need to change the date format that comes from datepicker.

Example:

```
$mydate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));
```

```js
$("#Date").datepicker({
    autoclose:true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
})


$("#Date2").datepicker({
    autoclose:true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
})

$("#Date3").datepicker({
    autoclose:true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    format: "yyyy-M-dd"
})

$("#Date4").datepicker({
    autoclose:true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    format: "dd-M-yyyy"
})


$("#Date5").datepicker({
    autoclose:true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    format: "dd/M/yyyy"
})

$("#Date6").datepicker({
    autoclose:true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    format: "yyyy/M/dd"
})
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>

1) dd-mm-yyyy : <input type="text" id="Date" placeholder="01-12-2016" />
<br><br>

2) yyyy-mm-dd : <input type="text" id="Date2" placeholder="2016-12-01" />
<br><br>
3) yyyy-M-dd : <input type="text" id="Date3" placeholder="2016-Dec-01" />
<br><br>
4) dd-M-yyyy : <input type="text" id="Date4" placeholder="01-Dec-2016" />
<br><br>
5) dd/M/yyyy : <input type="text" id="Date5" placeholder="01/Dec/2016" />
<br><br>
6) yyyy/M/dd : <input type="text" id="Date6" placeholder="2016/Dec/01" />
```

Comment: I did that, but it will send the date to server in dd-mm-yyyy format. What I want is to let the user pick the date in "dd-mm-yyyy" format, but send it to the server "yyyy-mm-dd" format

Comment: you have to change the format before store in database

Comment: @user3429660  ... Just Do This... $mydate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date']));

Comment: This will not work, as the `strototime` has no way of knowing the user's locale: one user can add have Y-m-d as preferences, other user might have d-m-Y, other m-d-Y etc. 

I could process the date in PHP based on user's preferences stored in DB, but I don't want to do that as I consider this  a "front-end" problem. 

I'll assume that it is not possible, so I'll switch to JQueryUI.

Comment: $("#date").data('datepicker').getFormattedDate('yyyy-mm-dd');

Comment: use this and then get the data using ajax .. on server side